# When to use volatile with register/local variables

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, volatile, nvcc

What is the meaning of declaring register arrays in CUDA with volatile qualifier?

When I tried with volatile keyword with a register array, it removed the number of spilled register memory to local memory. (i.e. Force the CUDA to use registers instead of local memory) Is this the intended behavior?

I did not find any information about the usage of volatile with regard to register arrays in CUDA documentation.

Here is the ptxas -v output for both versions

**With volatile qualifier**

```
    __volatile__ float array[32];
```

ptxas -v output

```
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z2swPcS_PfiiiiS0_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z2swPcS_PfiiiiS0_
88 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 47 registers, 16640 bytes smem, 80 bytes cmem[0], 8 bytes cmem[16]
```

**Without volatile qualifier**

```
    float array[32];
```

ptxas -v output

```
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z2swPcS_PfiiiiS0_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z2swPcS_PfiiiiS0_
96 bytes stack frame, 100 bytes spill stores, 108 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 51 registers, 16640 bytes smem, 80 bytes cmem[0], 8 bytes cmem[16]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `volatile` qualifier specifies to the compiler that all references to a variable (read or write) should result in a memory reference and those references must be in the order specified in the program. The use of the `volatile` qualifier is illustrated in Chapter 12 of the Shane Cook book, "CUDA Programming".

The use of `volatile` will avoid some optimizations the compiler can do and so change the number of used registers used. The best way to understand what `volatile` is actually doing is to disassemble the relevant `__global__` function with and without the qualifier.

Consider indeed the following kernel functions

```
__global__ void volatile_test() {

   volatile float a[3];

   for (int i=0; i<3; i++) a[i] = (float)i;
}

__global__ void no_volatile_test() {

   float a[3];

   for (int i=0; i<3; i++) a[i] = (float)i;
}
```

Disassembling the above kernel functions one obtains

```
code for sm_20
      Function : _Z16no_volatile_testv
.headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)" 
/*0000*/        MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100]; /* 0x2800440400005de4 */
/*0008*/        EXIT ;                 /* 0x8000000000001de7 */


      Function : _Z13volatile_testv
.headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)"
/*0000*/        MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100]; /* 0x2800440400005de4 */   
/*0008*/        ISUB R1, R1, 0x10;     /* 0x4800c00040105d03 */   R1 = address of a[0]
/*0010*/        MOV32I R2, 0x3f800000; /* 0x18fe000000009de2 */   R2 = 1
/*0018*/        MOV32I R0, 0x40000000; /* 0x1900000000001de2 */   R0 = 2
/*0020*/        STL [R1], RZ;          /* 0xc8000000001fdc85 */
/*0028*/        STL [R1+0x4], R2;      /* 0xc800000010109c85 */   a[0] = 0;
/*0030*/        STL [R1+0x8], R0;      /* 0xc800000020101c85 */   a[1] = R2 = 1;
/*0038*/        EXIT ;                 /* 0x8000000000001de7 */   a[2] = R0 = 2;
```

As you can see, when NOT using the `volatile` keyword, the compiler realizes that `a` is set but never used (indeed, the compiler returns the following warning: *variable "a" was set but never used*) and there is practically no disassembled code.

Opposite to that, when using the `volatile` keyword, all references to `a` are translated to memory references (write in this case).